# how to add 0 to the beginning of a file name only if there is one digit number?

Tags: powershell, filenames

I would need to add the 0 to the beginnig of the filenames but just if it is like one digit number at the biginnig of the name. For instance , name: "1 Photo.jpg" change to "01 Photo.jpg". Names with two digit on the beginning like 10 12 13 or "14 Photo.jpg" shall be unchanged.

I have just this:

```
dir|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(0,'0') + $_.Extension}
```

but this add 0s to all files without exception for two digit numbers.

Comment: If you were starting over you could do `1..14 | % tostring 00photo`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where-Object` before `Rename-Item` to include only those files that start with a digit and are followed by any non numeric character:

```
dir -Filter *.jpg | Where-Object Name -Match '^\d\D' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.insert(0, '0') + $_.Extension }
```